# How to index an array using a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have an `k=4` dimensional array

```
A = np.zeros([3,3,3,3])
```

but `k` is not known in advance or very large. How can I use a list

```
i = [1,1,1,1]
```

to get the element

```
A = [1,1,1,1]
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, Python passes a tuple when you provide more than one dimension to a `numpy` array. So what you want is just `A[tuple(i)]`.

Demo:

```
>>> A = np.arange(81).reshape(3,3,3,3)
>>> i = [1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> A[1,1,1,1]
40
>>> A[tuple(i)]
40
```